# Can we build Web Service in Java/PHP that create a native .NET DataSet object to be consumed by VB.NET?

Tags: java, php, vb.net, web-services

Hello dearest community,

We had plan to create a three tiered architecture database application, where the middle tier will be implemented using Web Service. We're going to use Linux for the server, so I think for the web service to be able to be implemented, we only had PHP/Java left. Is this right?

The constraint is, we're going to use VB.NET for the client application.
We already had a two tiered VB.NET application from our last successfull database application. It use a lot of DataSet for the result of SQL execution.

Now, what I had in mind, is a simple approach of converting all procedure that return a DataSet Object, to be a WebService method. But, because of this thinking, I don't think we can do it in Java/PHP. That is, we'll be enforce to use a ASP.NET approach. Is this correct? I assume my answer from this article [Consuming a DataSet from an XML Web Service (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s5xy331f.aspx)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No... You could use MONO to implement the webservice in .NET on Linux http://monodevelop.com/Feature_List and you would have a fully .Net solution (which would give you some potential to share code between client and server)

Comment: Your assumption is correct, however it's transparent what ever generates the XML, can be Java, PHP or locomotive basic.

Comment: @JonAlb : your answer here, could be my accepted answer for this question. But, after I review competent_tech answer, it's quite clear, that his/her solution is much more robust. I'll have for competent_tech answer for my next solution,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataSet are generally not usable outside of the Microsoft framework and, in fact, are not even supported in various Microsoft platforms, including Silverlight.

Unless there is an incredibly compelling need, such as tens of thousands of existing dataset-generating lines of code, I would strongly suggest that you switch to a class-based interface.

It is definitely more work and not nearly as easy or convenient as a DataSet, but the dividends will be substantial once you have made the initial investement.

For example, we converted a strongly DataSet-based application to a full class implementation and since then we have been able to create consumers in both Silverlight and Mono with no additional effort.

Comment: I like your solution @competent_tech! So, because it's a class based interface, we can code the WebService in any language that support it. Do you have, if you willing, share the code about what exactly is a class-based interface? So, after the data is gather from a MySQL/any database server, we must convert it into a class?